# How do you say "x still has much support"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, orden-de-palabras

How to translate `'...this shows that 'Jack' (still) has much support'` ?

What is the best and correct way (style of writing). It doesn't have to be translated 'literally'.

- Jack tiene el máximo apoyo del público.
- Esto demuestra que Jack todavía tiene mucho apoyo.
- Se nota que Jack aún tiene mucho apoyo.

What would be the best and most powerful combination?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say:

> Esto muestra que Jack aún tiene mucho apoyo.

Pure and simple. Don't complicate yourself on finding perfect translations.

Your last two attempts work fine.

---

We can use the *present perfect* to introduce a completed action with a result in the present:

> Esto muestra que Jack ha tenido mucho apoyo = Aún lo tiene.

Basically, a rephrased sentence with a result in the present.

Comment: I'd say attempts 2 and 3 are fine but not the first one because "much" is "mucho" or "bastante" but not "máximo" and it also lacks of the "still = todavía" part

Comment: @DGaleano I miswrote that. It's actually as you said.